# setInterval seems to only happen once? react setState js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create my own version of Pong in React, just as a fun project, and I'm trying to make the ball move every second. I call `componentWillMount()` in my `Game` component, setting an interval to handle the ball move. It works the first time, but then the ball disappears and doesn't work the next time. I actually don't know if the problem is from `setInterval()` or from the `handleBallMove()` function, because it moves the ball once, then clears it, so it seems like it runs again. `this.state.ball` is passed into a `Ball` component to render it, so it should rerender it, but it isn't. Can someone please help me?

Code (this is within a `Game` component):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
    this.handleBallMove();
  }, 1000);
}

handleBallMove() {
    ctx.clearRect(this.state.ball.x, this.state.ball.y, 15, 15);
    this.setState({
      ball: {
        x: this.state.ball.x + this.state.ball.vector[0],
        y: this.state.ball.y + this.state.ball.vector[1]
      },
    });
 }
//this is not inside of the Game component
class Ball extends React.Component {
  render() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    return (
      <div>{ctx.fillRect(this.props.ball.x, this.props.ball.y, 15, 15)}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `ball.vector` is just an array that tells the ball how far to move, and the `Ball` is rendered with a canvas.

Edit: `ctx` is defined, just separately. I didn't think to put that here, because it's just something to reference the canvas. Here you go:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (c.getContext) {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
}
```

And yes, "canvas" is a defined element that is a `<canvas id="canvas">` tag. That is not the problem here. Other things work from this. My problem is that the ball is cleared, but is not rerendered, even though its props change, after the first time.

Edit: added the `Ball` class to the code snippet, and also here's the full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pong-st4mt).

Edit: problem solved!

Comment: Well `setInterval()` does actually work, so the problem is in your code. Have you done any debugging, perhaps by `console.log()` to check the values of the ball coordinates?

Comment: I have. I put console.log() into the setInterval(), and it only outputted one set of ball coordinates.

Comment: Since you are doing animations you should look into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) since that is called before the browser is going to paint the window.

Comment: Bu the way, you can bind "this" when you define the setInterval: `setInterval(this.handleBallMove.bind(this), 1000);`

Comment: This is not valid code (ctx not defined) so you need to paste what you are actually working with. Or if it's really your code it's normal that it doesn't work.

Comment: _"My problem is that the ball is cleared, but is not rerendered, even though its props change."_ - You call `clearRect` to erase the canvas, you update the ball's position using `setState`, but **you never redraw the ball**.

Comment: Doesn't react automatically rerender a component if its props change? Because the state is passed in as a prop to a ball component, which should rerender when it gets those props. If this wouldn't rerender, then how do I force it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

At second glance I think I see what's going on. Save yourself the pain and convert your `Ball` component into a function component.

Component classes can have some really confusing behavior. Property changes do not immediately trigger re-renders. It is state changes that do that (caused by `this.setState(...)`).

It is necessary to implement a static component method that tells React how to derive new state from updated property values. It is literally called [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). For more complex components that manage a lot of internal state that method can be a pain in the neck to get right if performance is important to you.

Given the simplicity of your `Ball` component you'd be probably better off to rewrite it as a so-called "fully controlled" component, i.e. state is removed from inside your component, and the parent context sets up the entire state of the `Ball` component through properties.

I also noticed that your ball component renders a `<div>` tag. That doesn't seem to be necessary to me. Your ball already knows how to render itself using the graphics rendering context you're passing in. Just use that and return `null` instead:

```
function Ball(props) {
    const {ball, ctx} = props;

    ctx.clearRect(ball.x, ball.y, 15, 15);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, 15, 15)

    // You're using graphics context for rendering. No need for creating HTML element
    return null;
}
```

See also [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) for more information.